# Requestanimationframe usage issue

Tags: html, canvas, requestanimationframe

I got the following RequestAnimationframe function from http://my.opera.com/emoller/blog/2011/12/20/requestanimationframe-for-smart-er-animating

I am trying to use it. But not sure how to call it and use it. Can someone give me a simple example. I am new to this html5 animation thing so you can understand..

I will really appreciate any help! The function is below..

```
    (function() {
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelRequestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+
          'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }

    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); }, 
              timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };

    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        };
}())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just paste that code into your JS or in its own file and put this inside of your rendering function at the very bottom.

```
requestAnimationFrame(yourrenderingfunction);
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/Ts2g6/)**

```
// requestAnimationFrame shim
(function() {
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelRequestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+
          'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }

    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); }, 
              timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };

    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        };
}())



// Sprite unimportant, just for example purpose
function Sprite(){ 
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 50;
}

Sprite.prototype.draw = function(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
}


// setup
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0],
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;

//init the sprite
var sprite = new Sprite();

// draw the sprite and update it using request animation frame.
function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,200);

    sprite.x+=0.5;
    if(sprite.x>200){
        sprite.x = 0;            
    }
    sprite.draw();

    // makes it update everytime
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

// initially calls the update function to get it started
update();
```

Comment: Yes yes!! Thanks alot Loktar. You made a perfect example for me to understand :) I have marked your answer as correct :)